# My Docker container for a MEAN website dashboard does not work in Docker. Nodejs keeps restarting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For a project at university I am working on I am trying to get a MEAN stack website up and running via docker images and containers. However, when I run the command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

It results in this: [nodejs permanently restarting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqKyn.png).

When the command is run, I get these messages, at various points, which look like errors to me:

> failed to get console mode for stdout: The handle is invalid.

and

> nodejs exited with code 0

and then it seems like the connection to the MongoDB keeps starting and ending with these errors:

```
db        | 2021-03-30T08:50:22.519+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.21.0.2:39627 #27 (1 connection now open)
db        | 2021-03-30T08:50:22.519+0000 I NETWORK  [conn27] end connection 172.21.0.2:39627 (0 connections now open)
```

Prior to running the above command I have tested the website will work without a connection to MongoDB with: `docker build .` in the Angular root folder containing the `Dockerfile` and the Express API aspect of it works as I can visit the dashboard at `http://localhost:3000/`.

The full command process I run to achieve the failed state image linked above is as follows:
`docker-compose pull` → `docker-compose build` → `docker-compose up --build`.

I am using Docker Desktop and running the commands in Powershell on Windows 10 Pro.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
# We use the official image as a parent image.
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Copy the file(s) from your host to your current location.
COPY package*.json ./

# Change the user to node. This will apply to both the runtime user and the following commands.
USER node

# Run the command inside your image filesystem.
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Building the webstie
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/ng build

# Add metadata to the image to describe which port the container is listening on at runtime.
EXPOSE 3000

# Run the specified command within the container.
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

And my docker-compose.yml is:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=db
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js
  db:
    image: mongo:4.1.8-xenial
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

These are the same files that have been provided by the University and supposedly work.

I am new to Docker and containerization but shall try and provide you with any additional information, should you need it.

Comment: This might be related -> https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8186

Comment: When you create multiple images with docker-composer, composer generates a common network to communicate images. Are you using that network when trying to connect DB? In you codes that should be `db`. You have to use it like this `db:DBHOST`

Comment: Can you try exposing the PORT in the db service: 

ports:
    - 27017:27017

Comment: Hi @Murat , I'm not sure how I would do that? Would it be a change to the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Hi @Jotham, I'll try that shortly and get back to you, thanks :)

Comment: Hi @JothamArdel I tried adding "27017:27017" to my docker-compose.yml file and also exposed it in my Dockerfile but no luck.

Comment: The db service is running fine, it's the container running node. I can see from your Dockerfile you are pulling node:10-alpine image and in your docker-compose.yml you're saying Docker should build the image from the Dockerfile but then under the nodejs service you are still pulling the latest version of node. So which are you using the node:10-alpine image or nodejs(which pulls the latest image)